# Spring Scheduler Cron Job

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have two requirements.

1. Trigger job on every monday
2. Trigger job on first monday of each month

For the first requirement, I tried `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 ? * MON")` and `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 ? * 2")`. Neither of them are working. The function is not getting invoked.

For the second requirement, I tried `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 ? 1/1 MON#1")` and `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 ? 1/1 2#1")`. I'm getting the below error.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'monthlyData': For input string: "2#1" ".

Comment: Could you please edit your question and format the code?

Comment: You probably followed the Spring documentation on how to enable `@Async` and `@Scheduled` support?

Comment: Try using http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 1):

Both cron expressions are valid and represent what you wrote, now, via XML config, the following example seems to work for me:

```
<bean id="cronTriggerJobFirstMonday"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="YourQuartzJobBean" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 12 ? * MON#1 *" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerJobFirstMonday" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Actually I'm not using xml config.Instead I'm using @scheduled annotation in spring.Moreover,I gave ur Cron expression in the code.It throws an error,'it consists of seven digits,only six digits are allowed'.pls help

Comment: @Pharthi you must use annotation ? and you should provide the using version & minimum code so we could reproduce this issue, you might found something worth opening an issue at github

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

For every monday - (0 0 12 ? * MON) [sec min hour dayOfmonth month dayofweek]

First monday of each month - (0 0 12 ? * 2#1) - it will trigger event first monday of every month at 12

Comment: For every Monday,(0 0 12 ? * 1) this expression is working.Initially I gave Monday value as 2 which is wrong.For first Monday of the month,it throws the error which I stated in the question

Comment: have you tried (0 0 12 ? * 2#1) this for first monday of every month ?